# /root/.bash_profile: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to set java path. i am getting an error in .bash_profile. I don't know why. It seems everything good.

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs


JAVA_HOME=/apps/erp/java/jdk1.7.0_71


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:
\$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar

export PATH
```

Comment: did you check your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Going by the error message in your question title, the error is in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: `export PATH` must be `export $PATH`

Comment: Where is $HOME defined?

Comment: Why you have the jar files in your `PATH`? Think you `Need` them in the `CLASSPATH`

Comment: @Jens It might work, but it should also work *without* the dollar-sign. Don't want to expand the variable when exporting it.

Comment: By the way, are you really having a newline in the `PATH` assignment? Is the `tools.jar` file really on its own line?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know that this works. But i do not think that OP want to print PATH. That's why i commented it

Comment: no, it's not a new line. continuation of the previous line. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Then please edit it to be correct. Preferably just copy-paste the original file, as is without any editing of it. Because now it's still wrong with the newline in another position but not correct. Is the newline really where you show? As I said, copy-paste the file straight off, without any editing of it. Trying to rewrite code can introduce other errors that distracts from the actual problem.

Comment: Guys, please Help me. I'm running out of time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. You are calling a non-existing program on line 9, that's the problem. The file doesn't even *have* 16 lines, so how can there be an error on line 16?

Comment: @Aishu: That's not how it works. You haven't even asked an answerable question yet. *Once* you ask a question that is understandable and answerable, the community will answer it. Or not. On their own time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably this here:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:
\$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

The continuation backslash should be on the *previous* line, the line you want to be *continued*:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:\
$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

Or just keep it on a single line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
```

Comment: That "path" line is one line in my file. here I cannot put in one line. It is automatically doing word wrap.

Comment: @Aishu *What* is "automatically doing word wrap"? Your editor? Your terminal window? Have you tried making the window containing the text output *larger*? And what editor are you using? Because with the code you show that extra linebreak is the only possible reason you could possibly get an error.